# how to extract a tuple from list of tuples in python

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples :

```
a=[(1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (1, 500, 600)]
```

i wish to have the first bracket :

```
b= (1, 1, 1)
```

How to do that ? sorry i am a beginner

Comment: simple do `b = a[0]`

Comment: Please review the basics: http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
b = a[0]
```

Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You do it just like you'd take a string from a list of strings, or an integer from a list of integers, that is `b = a[0]` just as @user3030010 has it.

The deeper understanding here is that a tuple is just a particular kind of object, and *any* time you want an object from a list of objects you use something like `l[index]` for any list.